# Heroku scheduler: Sending email upon Rake task failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm running Rake tasks on Heroku with the scheduler add-on, as part of a Rails app. Is there an easy way to get notification emails if a task fails (i.e., raises an exception)? Ideally the email would include the stack trace and also any output generated up to that point by the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great add-on, [Airbrake](https://www.airbrake.io/pages/home), you might want to look into. It does everything that you're asking for, except output generated by the task. You could get rake task output with another plugin such as [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/).

Comment: Airbrake looks like a valid option, though for this particular little hobby project it's a bit overkill (and not free).

Comment: I haven't used this personally, but you could check out this gem: https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification

Comment: Cool, I can definitely build on top of that.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up fixing my issue more comprehensively by writing an extension to exception_notification for Rake tasks, called [notification_exception-rake](https://github.com/nikhaldi/exception_notification-rake). I also wrote a [blog post](http://blog.nikhaldimann.com/2013/02/19/failure-notifications-for-rake-tasks-on-the-heroku-scheduler/) specifically about how to use it on Heroku.